# Various connection time to SQL Server accross a LAN

Tags: connection, sql-server-express

I am connecting to a SQL Server Express 2005 on another PC on our company LAN.

On my PC (which has Windows7) the connection is immediate. On our tester PC (who has Windows XP), the connection takes about 5 to 6 seconds every time. This is the same network and the same server.

I am not talking about a connection through an application, but also through the control panel or anything else.

Any suggestion where this time difference may be coming from, what setup option might be involved or how we can speed up the connection on the XP PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the XP computer using an IPv4 address while you and the server are using IPv6? Could be an issue with the routers/switches along the way.

Comment: It is not that? The server and the network are not configured to use IPv6. We found the problem however. It was in the conversion between the computer name and the IP address.

We use "computer name\sqlexpress" to create the connection. Replacing with "ip address\sqlexpress" sovled the problem. Thanks for your suggestion that helped us figuring the answer.

Comment: That was going to be my next suggestion based on your answer to the previous question. :)